# Osculating conics in normal sections of a surface: how to generalize Euler's equation?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry

Well known background: Consider a differentiable surface in $\mathbb{R}^3$ and a point $p$; a normal plane at $p$ is a plane containing the normal vector. It is a classical result that the curvature of the intersection of a normal plane in $p$ and the surface (the normal section) has a curvature in $p$ depending on the normal plane and that maximum and minimum value of this curvature (known as principal curvatures $k_1$ and $k_2$) occur at perpendicular directions of the normal plane.

The dependence of the curvature in the normal section on the angle of the normal plane is given by $k(\alpha) = k_1 \cos^2 \alpha + k_2 \sin^2 \alpha$ with $\alpha$ being the angle with respect to the direction where the principal curvature $k_1$ occurs. Sometimes this equation is called Euler’s equation (one of many).

Now we consider in the normal section the osculating conic at $p$ (in the sense of question [Osculating conics and cubics and beyond](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/28044/osculating-conics-and-cubics-and-beyond)). 
Thus we don’t have any more an osculating circle defining the curvature $k(\alpha)$ in each normal section, but an osculating conic with in general two focal points, semi-axis and eccentricity.

Some questions seem to be very natural, but I couldn’t find any results:

- What is the surface built by the set of the osculating conics at a point $p$ (if we vary the normal section)? It does not seem to be an osculating quadric at point $p$ for the reason that the osculating conic in the normal section does not need to be symmetric with respect to the normal vector in $p$, whereas normal sections of an osculating quadric are (or am I mistaken here?).
- How do the characteristic parameters (take e.g. the eccentricity) of
  the osculating conics depend on the normal plane, is there an analogous equation to the one of Euler for the curvature (of the osculating circle)?
- Is there an explicit description of this surface in terms of the
  partial derivations of $f$, if the surface is given as a graph $f(x,y)$ (let’s assume wlog $f_{x}= f_{y} =0$).
- If all the osculating conics in the normal sections are parabolic (in
  the sense of the above mentioned question), what does this mean for the original surface at point $p$?

Comment: There are some interesting questions here, but I think you need to clarify some things. For example, it's not clear what you mean by 'ocsculating quadric' at a point on a surface in $3$-space.  As is well-known, while there is always a 6-parameter family of quadrics that osculate to second order to a (smooth) surface at a given point, there is generally no quadric that osculates to third order at that point, and when there is,  it is not unique. (In fact, if a surface has nonvanishing Gauss curvature and at each point there is a quadric that osculates to 3rd order there, it must be a quadric.)

Comment: @ Rober Bryant: Many thanks. I meant in the first question that the surface built by the set of the osculating conics at a point p (if we vary the normal section) does not seem to be *any* of the second order osculating quadrics at that point.

Comment: P.S. But I can be mistaken here. (Then the question would be whether the specific quadric out of the family of second order osculation quadrics which is equal to the surface built by the set of the osculating conics at a point p is wellknown/has been studied before.) P.S. By the way, I thought the family of quadrics having a contact of second order with an analytic surface at a given point is three-dimensional, cf. e.g. the beginning of 
 https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.bams/1183506630.

Comment: Ach!  That was a typo.  I meant to write '3-parameter family', not '6-parameter family' which is obviously wrong.  Sorry about that.  (I had cut out a remark about the space of quadrics that osculate to first order has dimension 6, and I garbled it.)